# How to make XQuartz listen to port 6000?

Tags: catalina, firewall, x11, xquartz

I have installed XQuartz 2.8.1 onto macOS Catalina 10.15.4. Now I can use

```
ssh -X myremotehost
```

and do

```
xcalc &
```

there.

But the `-X` option appears to work too slow. I am using a `LAN` and would like to pass `X` traffic directly. Unfortunately, I am getting

```
 Error: Can't open display: 192.168.MY.IP:0
```

and nothing is listening on port 6000 on my MacOS.

How do I get XQuartz/whatever to listen?

Firewall is off.

Comment: Is the Mac and the remote host on the same local network?

Comment: Yes. And I don't see somebody is listening 6000 with lsof

Comment: What is the IP of myremotehost (just the first bits will do)